# Is there a way to see variable as a string in visual studio c++ debugger?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

In java, if the toString method is overridden, then the debugger can be configured to show a string for the object.

In c++ debugger in visual studio , is there a way to see objects in string as well?